# How EJB 3.X Stateful session bean maintains state?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, state, stateful-session-bean

I am kind of new to EJB. I have understanding how HTTPSession is maintained (all cookies funda). All the resource in the internet says " Stateful Session Bean Maintenance session(remembers client). But I could not find answer to

How Stateful Session maintenance state ?

Oracle docs says

> The state of an object consists of the values of its instance
>   variables. In a stateful session bean, the instance variables
>   represent the state of a unique client/bean session. Because the
>   client interacts (“talks”) with its bean, this state is often called
>   the conversational state.

Thanks.

Comment: No. I am sorry, this is not duplicate  as in the other question has discussion about "stateless" bean. My question is about "stateful" bean.

Comment: Not sure what link was given, but this question is definitely easier to understand if you really understand how stateless beans work (basically, in stateless beans, every method call doesn't necessarily refer the same instance, but this is not true for stateful beans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance is created when you first get a reference to the bean and you can only use this reference to maintain state through.
Instance is destroyed when you call the method annotated with @Remove or the bean instance times out.

Source, the EJB JSR : [download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/). Chapter 4.6

Comment: Thanks!. Unfortunately there is no clear official document which explains this I found example https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/java-ee-stateful-session-bean-ejb-example.html.. Please add if you find any official document which explains this.

Comment: @malatesh I also learned the hard way never to rely on tutorials and peoples anecdotal knowledge, you are completely right not to. When I'm in doubt I read the JSR proposal: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/ . Chapter 4.6

Comment: @malatesh This is all explained in the EJB specification.  It's large and complicated, which is why many people rely on examples.

Comment: Thanks for official document.